# What does the underscore character mean in this Javascript code sample?

Tags: javascript, syntax, electron

I'm going through an Electron course, and the instructor keeps using this syntax:

```
click: _ =>{
console.log('clicked about')
}
```

What does the underscore refer to?

Comment: it's a variable, usually it denotes a not used one.

Comment: It's a shorter version of `() => { console.log('clicked about') }`. It saves you a whole byte!

Comment: both are a longer version of `_ => console.log('clicked about')` which saves at least 3 bytes!

Comment: Note that this is likely a bad placeholder in practice, because the underscore is the de facto alias for the very popular Lodash/Underscore utility libraries.

Answer (score 1):

The underscore in this case is just a placeholder for a variable that he is not using. Most regular names for the argument would be `e`, or `event`.

This is the equivalent of:

```
click: function(_) {
  console.log('clicked here');
}
```

If you used that argument, it might be more like:

```
click: function(event) {
  console.log('clicked on', event.target);
}
```

Your instructor is using ES6 fat arrow functions, where the parenthesis are optional when only one argument is supplied. This is the equivalent with a named argument for `event` and using parenthesis:

```
click: (event) => {
  console.log('clicked on', event.target);
}
```

Comment: So is this placeholder a javascript thing? Why not just write the function with no parameter? Is that not allowed?

Comment: @Dbloom, it's an aesthetics thing, no parameters means you'd need to use `() => { ... }` instead of `_ => { ... }`, e.g. 2 characters instead of one

Comment: The underscore is just the locally scoped name of the event argument. It is likely simply a convention that your instructor follows if he/she is not using the argument instead of simply omitting it entirely. The underscore as a variable or argument name has no special meaning in JavaScript.